# Setting a custom paragraph CSS class with Remirror

Tags: reactjs, prose-mirror, remirror

I've been looking into Remirror for a reimplementation of our `contenteditable`-based editor.

Seems great, easy enough to set up and do some basic customization of. The problem is that one key part of the editor is to use CSS classes for formatting various document elements. However, while the provided Remirror extensions allow application of inline `span`s and node formatting as a `NodeExtension` *specifically* using the `style` attribute, there doesn't seem to be any existing functionality to modify the `class` attribute on a paragraph in the Remirror document (and subsequently in the DOM representation).

Or am I missing something?

Is this something someone has done? Or can provide some insight into how it might be done?